# React Native + Onesignal / navigation or popup with push notification

Tags: react-native, onesignal, react-navigation

I am using React Native, react-native-onesignal, and react-navigation. When my action button in the push notification is pressed, I am trying to navigate to a screen or just show a modal pop up that I can render another screen in.

I cannot get this to work. I keep getting errors like:
"Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined" or "this.setState is not a function"

I have tried to navigate to another screen and I have tried to set a visible state to true of a modal popup and failed to succeed at both. So, I think I may be misunderstanding something all together with my approach.

Here is some code to help everyone further understand the problem:

**note:** I am aware that I don't have a 'navigation' prop reference, but I am not sure how to access it. I thought is was available to me from the child element in my router.js file.

**additional note:** I think the problem is because I am trying to navigate somewhere or render a popup from the 'onOpened(openResult)' handler function. Not sure how to include this in the actual render part of the component if that is what is needed.

**THIS IS THE APP CONTAINER (index.js):**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Modal, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';
import { Root } from './config/router';

class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { modalVisible: false };
    this.setModalVisible = this.setModalVisible.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() { 
    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('registered', this.onRegistered);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
}

componentDidMount() {
    FingerprintScanner
    .isSensorAvailable()
    .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('registered', this.onRegistered);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
}

onReceived(notification) {
    console.log('Notification received: ', notification);
}

onOpened(openResult) {        
    console.log('Message: ', openResult.notification.payload.body);
    console.log('Data: ', openResult.notification.payload.additionalData);
    console.log('isActive: ', openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
    console.log('openResult: ', openResult);
    if (openResult.action.actionID === 'fingerprint_id') {           
        console.log('fingerprint_id: ', 'clicked');
        //this.props.navigation.navigate('tbdScreen');
        //or
        //this.setModalVisible(true)
    }
}

onRegistered(notifData) {
    console.log('Device had been registered for push notifications!', notifData);
}

onIds(device) {
console.log('userId: ', device.userId);
}

setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
}    

render() {        
    return (
             <Root>
                <View>
                     <Modal
                         animationType={"slide"}
                         transparent={false}
                         visible={this.state.modalVisible}                    
                     >
                         <View>
                             <Text>this is the modal!</Text>
                         </View>
                     </Modal>
                </View>
             </Root>
           );

}
}

export default App;
```

**THIS IS MY ROUTER FILE (router.js):**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import WelcomeScreen from '../screens/WelcomeScreen';
import AuthScreen from '../screens/AuthScreen';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';
import TBDScreen from '../screens/TBDScreen';

export const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
    home: {
        screen: HomeScreen
    },
    settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Settings'
    }
}
}
);

export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    welcome: {
        screen: WelcomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {            
            TabBarLabel: 'Welcome'
        }
    },
    auth: {
        screen: AuthScreen,
        navigationOptions: {            
            TabBarLabel: 'Auth'
        }
    },
    home: {
        screen: HomeStack,
        navigationOptions: {            
            TabBarLabel: 'HomeScreen'
        }
    }
},
{
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom'
});

export const Root = StackNavigator({
    Tabs: {
        screen: Tabs,
   },    
    tbdScreen: {
        screen: TBDScreen,
    }
},
{
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

I have also been looking into using Redux with my React Navigation to persist the navigation state. Maybe this is what I need to do to access the navigation actions of the router.js file from the App component in the index.js file?

Anyway, much thanks in advance as I have been stuck on this for a while and I'm looking to learn from this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your onOpened function does not have the right scope because it is being called within OneSignal's addEventListener function so you have to bind "this" as below.

Change
`OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);`

to

`OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened.bind(this));`

And you will have this.props.navigation.navigate available inside the onOpened function.

Comment: Tried this, still getting this.state or this.setState is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Just do as follows:

```
componentWillMount() { 
    this.onReceived = this.onReceived.bind(this);
    this.onOpened = this.onOpened.bind(this);
    this.onRegistered = this.onRegistered.bind(this);
    this.onIds = this.onIds.bind(this);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('registered', this.onRegistered);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
}
```